# How to deal with all keyevents when added a view with WindowManager?

Tags: java, android-intent, service, keyevent, android-windowmanager

Problem is on a service view back button is giving me a response but Home and Recent Apps button is not triggering

```java
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME: //Not getting
            minimizeApp();
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: //getting
            finish(false);
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH: //Not getting
            //minimizeApp();
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

in the same service, **I have tried** to add and remove different flags but can't gets what I want.

```java
mLayoutParams =new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN| 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON| 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
                    |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    ,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I am getting Back pressed but I want to catch Event of home and recent app pressed.

Comment: **I got the solution using** `code`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
I got the solution

```
  li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       LinearLayout lia=  new LinearLayout(this) {

            //home or recent button
            public void onCloseSystemDialogs(String reason) {

                if (reason.equals("homekey")){
                    finisha(false);
                }
                if (reason.equals("recentapps")){
                    finisha(false);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
                        || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME
                     ) {

                    //The Code Want to Perform.
               //     return true;
                }
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){

                }

                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH){

                }
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        };

        lia.setFocusable(true);

        final View root = (View) li.inflate(R.layout.layout_alias_locker, lia);
```